# Facing an error while calling groupby function?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

```
 for feature in categorical_features:
     data=df_train.copy()
     data.groupby(feature)['Frequency'].median().plot.bar()
     plt.xlabel(feature)
     plt.ylabel('Frequency')
     plt.show()
```

Gives me an error while calling the groupby function. It says that function has no attribute groupby

Comment: Try replacing `data=df_train.copy` by `data=df_train.copy()`

Comment: @Sheldore Hi. Sorry, that was a typo on my part. I've edited the question. :). Still getting the same error though.